# Kendo UI Editable Inline

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a problem in Kendo UI Im using GRID/INLINE EDITING using Razor, the problem is when I Click the Edit Button the textbox in Grid is not showing. This is my Code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
.Name("LocalGS")    
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(p => p.Country_No).Title("Country No").Width(140);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Effective_date).Title("Effective Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}").Width(160);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Scale_Min).Width(140);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Scale_Max).Width(140);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Currency).Width(100);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
    .Ajax()                 
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Country_No))
    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "SaladEntry"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("KendoUIGrid", "SaladEntry"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "SaladEntry"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
)
```

)

Can someone help me, I search solution in google but theres no answer for my question.

Comment: Is there an error being thrown in the F12 developer tools?

Answer (score 3):

Check all your Kendo CSS files are in place and being called.

Comment: More details in your answer or other suggestions are always good to have.

Answer (score 3):

Checks if the model property is read-only or not has setter